# Symfony 4 and Doctrine, how to generate repository automatically after mapping?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

All the tutorials I am finding have the repository created automatically using `make:entity` when creating new tables

but I have been importing from an existing database following the official [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html) with the following command: `php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import App\\Entity annotation --path=src/Entity`

This command does not seem to create any repository... and the documentation does not talk about generating a repository

I know I can create one manually but is there a command to generate them automatically ? I have 25 tables.... Would be very useful

lazy me oO

edit: I also tried `php bin\console make:entity --regenerate` but I get `no change` on all tables and no repository created

Comment: Do you really need custom repository classes for all of your entities? In most cases, custom repository classes are useless, dead code – unless you’re implementing custom repository methods, which is rather rare in my experience. Therefore it makes sense not to generate those stubs automatically.

Comment: Sam, don't go this way. Create the repository class only if you need it.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1**

You can simply run

```
php bin/console make:entity --regenerate
```

This will prompt and ask for:

```
Enter a class or namespace to regenerate [App\Entity]:
```

Just press Enter or specify the location of your entity folder, and it will create missing getters/setters & Repositories.

[image: test]

**---> WARNING:**
If it does not create the repositories make sure you have the following annotation in your entities :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\MyClassRepository")
 */
class MyClass
{

}
```

You also might want to **clear your cache** if it's not working (as noted by @Pavel Petrov in the comments)

**SOLUTION 2**

The SymfonyMakerBundle allows you to create your own makers. So you could make a new one called `make:repositories` that will generate a repository for each entity found in the /Entity folder.

To do that, create a class (MakeRepositories) that extends AbstractMaker in your `src/Maker/` directory. (documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html#creating-your-own-makers)

Use the core maker `make:entity` to help you create your new command (since it contains the code to generate a repository) : https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/blob/master/src/Maker/MakeEntity.php

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, forgot to mention I tried that but all I get is `no change` on all my tables. It is not creating any repo. Will update my question to reflect this

Comment: @Sam I added another possibility.

Comment: Not sure why solution 1 does not create anything ?? Tried solution 2, created a file `MakeRepositories.php` in `src/maker` then extended `AbstractMaker` then copied lines 135 to 295 from the make entity link in the class. Then I type  `./bin/console make:repositories` but it is not defined. where do I define it please? the doc says `Make sure your class is registered as a service and tagged with maker.command` but I don't understand

Comment: Do you have this annotation in your entities : @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\MyClassRepository") ?  (specifying the repository)

Comment: I did not but added `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\BikedbRepository")` and now it says `Cannot autowire service "App\Repository\BikedbRepository": argument "$entityClass" of method "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntit
  yRepository::__construct()" has no type-hint, you should configure its value explicitly.` when I run `make::entity --regenerate`

Comment: that's because I tried creating the repo manually and had `extends ServiceEntityRepository` for the class `BikedbRepository`. removed it, ran the command again and `no change` still

Comment: "Warning" part does the thing for me! Cool.

Comment: I wanted to add that you need to fully specify the path to your entity class as such: 

 Enter a class or namespace to regenerate [App\Entity]:
 > App\Entity\Community

Comment: Even after adding the `repositoryClass` attribute repositories weren't generated with `make:entity --regenerate`. I had to clear the cache and then it generated the repo classes.

Answer (score 8):

After generating your entity classes from database, add the following annotation to each of your entities:

```
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ClassNameRepository")
```

To genenerate the repository classes, run the following command:

```
php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App
```

Answer (score 5):

**How to Generate Entities from an Existing Database**

Table name: CamelCase (eg: table_name will be TableName)

`php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import App\\Entity annotation --path=src/Entity --filter="TableName"`

**How to Generate Entities**

Run below command, it will create entity file.

`php bin/console make:entity --regenerate`

Next, go to your entity file and add `@ORM\Entity repositoryClass`

**Example** Entity file

```
/**
 * XXXXXX
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="XXXX")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\XXXXRepository")
 */

class XXXXX {
```

Run again this command again, and it will create repository for you.

`php bin/console make:entity --regenerate`

Answer (score 0):

Do not copy the annotation too fast, I copied the annotation, but in my case the entities were generated automatically, so there was already a line ORM\Repository, which appeared after, delete it or replace it with the solution