# Symfony 4 get data from daabase

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Thx to this answer the problem have been solved :
[Symfony 4 and Doctrine, how to generate repository automatically after mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51774053/symfony-4-and-doctrine-how-to-generate-repository-automatically-after-mapping/51782017)

I have problem with getting data from a MySQL table,

Here is my Controller :

```
namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use App\Entity\EmailComponents;

class MigrationController extends AbstractController
{

/**
 * @Route("/migration", name="migration_script")
 */
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $entityManager = $this -> getDoctrine() -> getManager();

    $email = new EmailComponents();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($email)
        ->add('language', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => [
                'Anglais' => 'en',
                'Français' => 'fr',
                'Allemend' => 'de',
                'Néerlandais' => 'nl',
            ],
            ])
        ->add('subject', TextType::class)
        ->add('body', TextareaType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Crée Email'])
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $email = $form->getData();
        $entityManager -> persist($email);
        $entityManager -> flush();

        $this->addFlash('success', 'Email a été crée avec succès');

        return $this -> redirectToRoute('migration_script');
    }


    $search = $entityManager -> getRepository(EmailComponents::class) -> findAll();

    return $this->render('admin/migration/index.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form -> createView()
    ));
}
```

And here is the EmailComponents.php file :

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\EmailComponentRepository")
 */
class EmailComponents
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=2)
 */
private $language;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=250)
 */
private $subject;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=5000)
 */
private $body;


public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function getLanguage()
{
    return $this->language;
}

public function setLanguage($language)
{
    $this->language = $language;
}

public function getSubject()
{
    return $this->subject;
}

public function setSubject($subject)
{
    $this->subject = $subject;
}

public function getBody()
{
    return $this->body;
}

public function setBody($body)
{
    $this->body = $body;
}
}
```

The problem is that every time I run the page, I get this error message :

> The "App\Entity\EmailComponents" entity has a repositoryClass set to
>   "App\Repository\EmailComponentRepository", but this is not a valid
>   class. Check your class naming. If this is meant to be a service id,
>   make sure this service exists and is tagged with
>   "doctrine.repository_service".

The error come from this part:

```
$search = $entityManager -> getRepository(EmailComponents::class) -> findAll();
```

Comment: Have you created a EmailComponentRepository class in that namespace, in the correct directory?

Comment: Are you sure that `App\Repository\EmailComponentRepository` class is actually available and it is inherited from Doctrine's `EntityRepository`? Error message is all about it

Comment: Which version of Symfone are you using?

Comment: I think the problem is in line 7 of EmailComponents.php file. You should set the repository to App\Repository\EmailComponentsRepository (you're missing the "s" I think)

Comment: @JonStirling How can I create EmailComponentRepository class ? It shouldn't be created by Doctrine itself while first creating the table ? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution :

I used :

```
 php bin\console make:entity --regenerate
```

To generate missing classes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, for me it was because my entityRepository file was not a .php file ( but has php code in it), I feel stupid, phpstorm didn't help me because the coloration was correct.

I solved the problem with `php bin\console make:entity --regenerate` as [Sinf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54881327/12102888) said
Thanks!