# how and where to execute custom queries in symfony 4

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I am using an entity class which extends **ServiceEntityRepository** like this:

```
class Sms extends ServiceEntityRepository
{ 
   public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
   {
       parent::__construct($registry, Sms::class);
   }
... 
}
```

so when I need to persist an instance of the entity class in my controller file I need to pass the ManagerRegistry as the argument for my Entity class but I couldn't find a way to access the `ManagerRegistry` in my controller.

can anyone help?

Comment: The service might be private so you can't get it from the container with `$this->container->get(ManagerRegistry::class)`. Just inject the `ManagerRegistry` into your controller or override the service definition and make it public.

Comment: It would be very strange to have a Doctrine entity extend a repository.  No active record stuff in Doctrine.  So your approach is fundamentally wrong.  And as far as your question goes, the code you posted shows how to inject the registry into a class.  Not that you need to anyways.

Comment: I didn't quite follow a) why your entity is extending ServiceEntityRepository (which is meant to be extended by repository classes instead of entities) and b) why you need ManagerRegistry in your controller to save an entity instance?

Comment: I extend that because I was seeking "query Builder" in my entity class.

Comment: @Cerad and @ejuhjav - Guys relax `ServiceEntityRepository` is just an  `optional EntityRepository base class with a simplified constructor (for autowiring).`. I don't see any bad practice extending it - as it's meant to be. The class-name `Sms` might indicate a *"bad"* approach but it doesn't necessarily from the code in the question. Changing the class-name to `SmsRepository` might be more obvious, agreed :)

Comment: @NicolaiFröhlich can you provide an example or link for injecting that?? I just started Symfony and I am confused.

Comment: @ejuhjav - even injecting the `ManagerRegistry` instead of the `EntityManager` can be a completely valid approach. Read [this](https://matthiasnoback.nl/2014/05/inject-the-manager-registry-instead-of-the-entity-manager/) article.

Comment: @NicolaiFröhlich - "I am using an entity class which extends ServiceEntityRepository" I suppose the OP could be confusing what they are asking for but it seems pretty clear that they expect an entity.

Comment: @nicolai-fröhlich I think we got an answer there above that it wasn't just an indication of bad approach as the intention was to get hold of query builder in the entity class :)

Comment: @Cerad - your initial suspicion was correct then :)

Comment: So ... @mohamadaligharat - What exactly are you trying to do in your controller with this approach?

Comment: @NicolaiFröhlich is that valid for Symfony 4? I think YAML files are different.

Comment: Can't follow you here, sorry. Can you elaborate what you're actually trying to achieve by injecting a repository into your entity? Further: Why do you need the `ManagerRegistry` in your controller?

Comment: I am going to persist a new sms instance but for doing something like this: $mySMS = new Sms(); I need to pass the argument.

Comment: Can't follow again. Which argument do you need to pass where? Do you try to persist a simple entity (as described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#persisting-objects-to-the-database)) after creation or are you trying to do something more fancy?

Comment: I need the query builder in my Entity class to write some SQL code. by extending ManagerRegistry I could achieve this. is there a better way?

Comment: Yes just want to declare new instance completly like the link you provided.

Comment: As it has been said before you never need a query builder inside an entity class. I still don't understand what you're trying to do with the query-builder. What do you want to query for and where shall it end up?

Comment: If you just want to persist a new instance as described in the documentation -> just follow the tutorial :)

Comment: @NicolaiFröhlich
Search this in the doc "class ProductRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository" and see that section, I did this, but they did not say how to do newing an Entity class and giving it a ManagerRegistry object.

Comment: I know how to use the `ServiceEntityRepository` class. You just have to create the extending class and - in symfony - it's service will be autowired. What's the problem here? Do you get any exceptions? How and where are you trying to use your `SmsRepository`? Inside a controller you inject it or - if you're extending from `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController` - get it from the container like `$repository = $this->container->get(SmsRepository::class);`.

Comment: @NicolaiFröhlich - Relax!  The op is trying to use an active record approach with the Doctrine ORM which seldom ends well.  At some point they will realize that it is extremely difficult to ensure that an entity get's injected with something mostly because the ORM itself does not use the constructor when creating entities.  The OP could chose to use an active record ORM or they can chose to do things the Doctrine way.

Comment: @NicolaiFröhlich the problem was that I wanted to use my Entity class as a Repository class!

Comment: @mohamadaligharat - I see. Trying to tweak Doctrine towards an Active Record pattern won't work out well. Doctrine - unlike Eloquent - uses the Device Mapper pattern. Glad you managed to solve your issue. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that **ServiceEntityRepository** should be extended in a repository class, not an entity class. 
as it is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51774053/symfony-4-and-doctrine-how-to-generate-repository-automatically-after-mapping/51782017), there is no good description for auto-generating repositories from an existing database.
This is my entity class with its annotations:

```
/**
* Sms
*
* @ORM\Table(name="sms")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\SMSRepository")
 */
class Sms
{ ... }
```

this line is very important:
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\SMSRepository")

another important thing is to removing Entity from excluding in the services.YAML file.

if you set a name for the repository of your entity class by annotation, by running this command you will have your repository generated:

```
php bin\console make:entity --regenerate
```

and you can simply write you complex queries in the repository file which is generated by the aforementioned command.

for calling methods of your repository class you can use this in your controller files:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(EntityFile::class)->youFunctionNameInRepositoryFile()
```

be careful about the argument of the getRepository which is the Entity file, not the repository file.